# Android Book for development

Tags: android

I am new to Android and I was wondering which book to refer for development. Can anyone help me in this regard ??

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good book for beginning android development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114287/good-book-for-beginning-android-development)

Comment: just noticed the accepted answer in the question @CrazyCoder pointed , suggested a book that is very low rated on amazon

Comment: Taz, so use the answer with most upvotes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Personally i like the android development website:

http://developer.android.com/index.html

It's got a ton of references, example, tutorials, videos, example code the list goes on and on. Personally this and stack overflow are enough, but that's just my opinion.

Another good book-blog is "The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development" from CommonsWare user https://commonsware.com/Android/

Comment: Agree. I purchased the OReily book and it had so less info than this site

Comment: Hey, Thanx Stevy!! Actually I am following the android developer site itself, so was just wondering if any other good book is available in the market.

Comment: I personally dont think you need one. The developer site has just about everything you need to know. its really in depth and have a lot of helpful examples and such

Comment: The docs are not beginner-friendly, they once gave me 400 lines of weird-looking code with no explanation, and it was supposed to be a tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

I really like "[Professional Android 4 Application Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118102274)". It really walks you through everything very nicely.

Comment: Recently i buy this book (Professional Android 2 Application Development by Reto Meier).Im new to android.I had 2 years of experience in j2me.This book is not well organized.This book is not suited for beginners.This book is just a copy of the google online documentation.Im not able to understand a single concepts in this book.This book is wastage of cost.I cannot expect this kind of book from "Wrox" publications."Wrox" publication is good one."WroX" degrade their image with respect to this kind of books by "reto meier"

Answer (score 4):

[Pro Android 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430232226) is the biggest book on Android you will find, for around the same price as the other books. It covers Honeycomb too and has very good reviews.

Answer (score 2):

[Hello Android, 3rd Edition](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Hello-Android-Introducing-Development-Programmers/dp/1934356565/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1294799769&sr=8-1) is a very good book by example.

Comment: Thanks Taz..!! I Will look into that book.!!